# Automate text formatting in Python

Tags: python, text, formatting, txt

I have a txt file containing a list of country codes for each line. The format is like this:

```
AL
DZ
AS
AO
AI
BS
BB
BY
BJ
BA
```

I would like to format the text using Python, adding quotation marks for each country code, followed by a comma.

```
'AL',
'DZ',
'AS',
'AO',
'AI'
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing really :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:-

```
with open('flat.txt') as txt:
    cc = []
    for line in txt:
        cc.append("'"+line.rstrip('\n')+"'")
    print(',\n'.join(cc))
```

Another technique that also include writing to another file could look like this:-

```
with open('flatin.txt') as txtin:
    with open('flatout.txt', 'w') as txtout:
        txtout.write(',\n'.join(
            "'" + line.rstrip('\n') + "'" for line in txtin) + '\n')
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the output should be another txt file

Comment: Do you want me to write that part too?

Comment: That would be ideal, yes 

Comment: Quite right @Timus. I originally had the list comprehension declared outside the join() (into a temporary variable) then copied and pasted without thinking it through. Thanks for highlighting my error. I will edit the code

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that

```
with open('untitled.txt', 'r') as file:
    output =[]
    for l in file:
        output.append("'"+l.strip()+"',\n")
```

Comment: As with one of the other solutions, this will generate a redundant comma at the end

Comment: As far as i understanded author wanted a coma at the end of each line

Comment: Not according to the sample output he shows in his question

Comment: sorry You are right I adjusted anserw thanks

Comment: Now there won't be any commas!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is an unorthodox way to do that task in python, but if you want to do it with the fewest line only with stantard libs, than you can use the `inputfile` lib as follows:

```
$ cat test.txt 
AL
DZ
AS
AO
AI
BS
BB
BY
BJ
BA
$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fileinput
>>> for line in fileinput.input("test.txt", inplace=True):
...     print(line.replace(line, f"'{line.strip()}',"))
... 
>>> 

$ cat test.txt 
'AL',
'DZ',
'AS',
'AO',
'AI',
'BS',
'BB',
'BY',
'BJ',
'BA',
$
```

Comment: Unfortunately that results in a redundant trailing comma